# Touch Event Detection in UIImageView inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, drag-and-drop

I am trying to detect a touch event in  `UIImageView` which is added in `UITableViewCell`'s `contentView`. But, `Imageview` is not triggering the touch event, i have enabled the `imageview userinteraction` too. Basically, I am trying to drag image from `UItableViewcell` to somother view/place. do you guyz have the solution of it, dragging images from `UITableViewcell` to otherviews.

Comment: It's probably because (I think) the table cell class captures all touches to the contentView in order to call the delegate method `tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: @AndrewTetlaw  , Yes i exactly thinking the same way...but there must be someway to achive drag and drop effect from UITableViewCell aswell.,, I am despretly searching for the solution !!

Answer (score 0):

create a custom `UIView` and add `ImageView` on that `view` as a `subview`  then add touch event on that `view`.

then add that `view` on `Cell content View`